# A veritable chameleon

Tags: riddle, word

What's brown, then black, then bright, then white?

The solution to this riddle is one word.

(There are five answers that would be accepted; all are very similar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

> **FIREWOOD** - it is **brown** before the fire is lit, turns **black** as it chars, gives off **bright** light while it burns, and becomes **white** ash afterwards.

Comment: What does it have to do with the title?

Comment: @IsaacRoanSison It changes colors like a chameleon